# How to write 'and' in mathematical language?

Tags: terminology

How to write 'and' in mathematical language?

I'm not from the field of math, but I needed to write two very simple equations in the same small line and I'm afraid it'll be confusing since they're very close to each other. So I found it best to put a symbol which means "and", and it'll separate them. Does such a symbol exist?

Comment: We have the ampersand '&' and the logical and '$\land$'.

Comment: There is a symbol, but I wouldn't use it outside of logic. It makes things less readable. But, for posterity's sake, it is $\wedge$.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, is '&' also works for the next step'? For example 24*60=1440 & 1h=60min.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfectly good example:

Consider the equations

$$F(x,y)=0 \quad \text{and}\quad G(x,y)=0.$$

Comment: (Unnecessary symbols will often clutter your text. We are used to reading words, so why not keep it that way?)

Comment: So at least we know the meaning of the words. Did these symbols exist in the time of scholars like Gauss?  Or was it invented later?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: $\wedge$. For instance, you can write: let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers such that$$x^2+y=2=1\wedge y=2x.$$However, it is more common to write it as$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x^2+y^2=1\\y=2x.\end{array}\right.$$And there is nothing wrong in writing$$x^2+y=2=1\text{ and }y=2x.$$